# Limit access to topics?

Tags: ros, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this possible? I have topics that I want to share in my own subsystem, but don't want exposed to external nodes because it's really not data that they should be using.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201193/limit-access-to-topics?/) by [noobalot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21404/noobalot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no way to limit access to a specific topic. For this sort of limitation a common approach is to isolate the network with the internal subsystem and run the "public" master and use some of the multi-master tools to expose the specific topics you wish available on the public master.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2